# Action script 3 Event And Event dispacher

Tags: actionscript-3, events

what's diffrance between Event and EventDispacher

when I create Custom Event class how I create it and extend it to Event or eventDispacher ?

Answer (score 0):

EventDispatcher will, as it says in the name dispatch an event.
For example if your custom component implements IEventDispatcher, it will be able to dispatch events.

In Flash, all DisplayObjects can dispatch events by default.

In Flex, all UIComponents can dispatch events by default.

To create a custom event, you can do the following:

```
package{
import flash.events.Event;

public class MyCustomEvent extends Event
{
    private var _test:String;

    public function MyCustomEvent(test:String)
    {
        super("MyCustomEvent", false, false);
        this.test = test;
    }

    public function set test(value:String):void{
        _test = value;
    }

    public function get test():String{
        return test;
    }   
}}
```

Then to dispatch it, you either dispatch an event from a Display Object or you create a custom component that implements IEventDispatcher
and do this:

```
dispatchEvent(new MyCustomEvent("This is a test event"));
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
that's how you can extend a event : 
    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "customEvent";
        public var param:Object;

```
    public function BannerEvent( type:String, param:Object = null, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false ) 
    {
        super( type, bubbles, cancelable );
        this.param = param?param: { };
    }

}
```

}